# How to use the animation which is used to reveal the lower view?

Tags: objective-c, ios4

Does somebody know how to use the animation which is used to reveal the lower `view(Map,Satellite,Hybrid, List)` in the maps application?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have to create a new ViewController

Eg:

```
MyViewController *myvc = [[MyViewController alloc] initWithNibName: @"blablabla"];

[self presentModalViewCOntroller: myvc animated: YES];
```

Giving that MyViewController is a subclass of UIViewController for example and this i run from another viewcontroller.